# How would I go about changing to (x,y) position of an object

Tags: cocoa, position

I'm going to try to keep this relatively simple.  I have a NSImageView, and I would like to change it's (x,y) position on the screen programmatically.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add one programmatically, make sure you have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`, then set the frame of the NSImageView using the frame property

```
imageView.frame = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it